# I'm trying to graph a function for different values of Chi and Wn?

Tags: plot, graph, scilab

I'm trying to graph a function for different values of Chi and Wn. Here's the function.
[image]

```
A1=0.1
A2=0.2
A3=0.3       //Valores de chi
A4=0.4
A5=0.5
B1=29
B2=30
B3=65      //valores deW
B4=80
B5=100
C=1
u=linspace(0,600)
t=linspace(0,30)
r=((sqrt(1-A1^2))*B1)
r1=((sqrt(1-A2^2))*B2)
r2=((sqrt(1-A3^2))*B3)
r3=((sqrt(1-A4^2))*B4)
r4=((sqrt(1-A5^2))*B5)
x=(%e^(t-A1*B1))(    C*cos(r)*B1*t)'  +   ((C+(A1*B1*C))/((r)*B1))   *(sin(r)*B1*t) 
x1=(%e^(t-A2*B2))(    C*cos(r1)*B2*t)'  +   ((C+(A2*B2*C))/((r1)*B2))   *(sin(r1)*B2*t) 
x2=(%e^(t-A3*B3))(    C*cos(r2)*B3*t)'  +   ((C+(A3*B3*C))/((r2)*B3))   *(sin(r2)*B3*t) 
x3=(%e^(t-A4*B4))(    C*cos(r3)*B4*t)'  +   ((C+(A4*B4*C))/((r3)*B4))   *(sin(r3)*B4*t) 
x4=(%e^(t-A5*B5))*(    C*cos(r4)*B5*t)'  +   ((C+(A5*B5*C))/((r4)*B5))   *(sin(r4)*B5*t) 
xlabel("t")
ylabel("x(t)")
title("Grafica de la Ecuación")
plot(t,x,t,x1,t,x2,t,x3,t,x4)
```

I get Invalid error in line 19

Comment: Also, I wanted to export it to LaTex using prettyprint but I'm not sure how

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: The "Invalid index" error at line 19 was due to missing multiplication operator after the exponential part.

Answer (score 0):

You use too many useless parenthesis (sometimes forget needed ones), use dumb variable names (use the names of variables in the formula) and do not use use dot-prefixed operators. Here is a readable working code to do what you want:

```
clear

//Valores de zeta
zeta = 0.1:0.1:0.5 

//valores de omega
omega = [29 30 65 80 100]
x_0 = 1;
xdot_0 = 1;
t = linspace(0,3,1000)

for i=1:length(zeta)
    r = sqrt(1-zeta(i)^2)*omega(i);
    x(i,:) = exp(-zeta(i)*omega(i)*t).*(x_0*cos(r*t) + (xdot_0+zeta(i)*omega(i)*x_0)/r*sin(r*t))
end

clf
plot(t,x)
xlabel("t")
ylabel("x(t)")
title("Grafica de la Ecuación")
xstring(0.2,0.5,"$\large x(t)=\exp(-\zeta\omega_n t)\left\{ x_0\cos\left(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega_n t\right)+\frac{\dot x_0+\zeta\omega_n x_0}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega_n} \sin\left(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega_n t\right)\right\}$")
```

[image]